# How to return a bool value from aync/await function and pass it to other variable in other page

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I want check if device is connected to internet or not and i done with class that do this work and return to me a bool value and i use from this class to other page and pass returned value to bool variable but get get this error that say `Future<dynamic>` is not a subtype of type bool in type cast

```
import 'dart:io';

class CheckConnection{
  static Future<bool>  checkConnection() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
         return (await checkConnection()) == true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      print('not connected');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code? so we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place where you want to check you have to do like this:

```
CheckConnection.checkConnection().then((bool result){
  /* check result here  */
})
```

Or you can do this inside `async` function like `checkConnection`:

```
void _myFunction() async {
  bool result = await CheckConnection.checkConnection();
  /* check result here  */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you call checkConnection again inside for it (recursive effect). Are you sure you don't want to do like:

```
class CheckConnection {

  static Future<bool>  checkConnection() async {
    final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      return true;
    }
/* try catch also can be applied! */ 

    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return this

```
return await checkConnection();
```